Enhanced Input Ongoing Gamepad Stick Binding
My desired behavior is that the gamepad left stick 2d vector will send input every tick about its latest position.

When I EnhancedInputComponent->BindAction(AimAction, ETriggerEvent::Started ... then I receive 1 event every time the stick is moved past the actuation threshold - not cool because I don't receive further events when the position of the stick changes, or when it returns to 0
When I EnhancedInputComponent->BindAction(AimAction, ETriggerEvent::Ongoing ... then I receive no events at all.




I figured out the answer by creating a new First-Person Game with C++ (the default Unreal 5 template) and studying how they did Enhanced Input.
The Input Mapping Context has no triggers or modifiers:

The Input Action also has no triggers or modifiers:

Here's how I bound the action in ShipCharacter.cpp
void AShipCharacter::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
{
    Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(PlayerInputComponent);

    if (UEnhancedInputComponent* Input = CastChecked<UEnhancedInputComponent>(PlayerInputComponent))
    {
        Input->BindAction(MoveAction, ETriggerEvent::Triggered, this, &AShipCharacter::InputMove);
    }
}

void AShipCharacter::InputMove(const FInputActionValue& Value)
{
    const FVector2D V = Value.Get<FVector2D>();
    // todo stuff with the input
}

